# PHP Editing post

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

I'm having a very annoying problem.  Whenever I edit a post, the **first** time it gets edited, it will lose all of its information.   I can't figure it out, I've worked on it for 2 days.

Heres the form code:

```
<?php 
$post = htmlspecialchars($_GET["id"]);


$name = $_SESSION['Username'];
if (in_array($name, $allowedposters)) {
$results = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tool WHERE id = $post");
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($results)){


$title= $row['title'];
$details= $row['details'];
$date= $row['date'];
$author= $row['author'];
$id= $row['id'];



echo "<a href=story.php?id=";
echo $post;
echo ">Cancel edit</a> <br><br><b>";
echo $title;
echo "</b> <br><br>";
echo '
<form action="edit-new.php?story=';
echo $id;
echo '" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<textarea rows="1" cols="60" name="title" wrap="physical" maxlength="100">';
echo $title;
echo '</textarea><br>';
?>



<textarea rows="30" cols="60" name="details" wrap="physical" maxlength="10000">
<?php 
echo $details;
echo '</textarea><br>';

echo '<label for="file">Upload featured image:</label><br>
      <input type="file" name="file" id="file" />';
echo'<br><input type="submit" />';
}

} else {
  echo "Not enough permissions.";
}
?>
```

.
.

Here is the actual php code, inserting information into the database:

.
.

```
<?php
   $post = $_GET['story'];
   $title = $_POST['title'];
   $details = $_POST['details'];
         echo 'Updated.';
    $dbtype     = "mysql";
    $dbhost     = "localhost";
    $dbname     = "x";
    $dbuser     = "xx";
    $dbpass     = "xxx";
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$dbhost;dbname=$dbname",$dbuser,$dbpass);
    $sql = "UPDATE  tool SET title=:title, details=:details WHERE id = '$post'";
        $q = $conn->prepare($sql);
        $q->execute(array(
        ':details'=>$details,
        ':title'=>$title,
         ));
?>
```

Again, I would like to mention, the only problem is that, the **first** time I edit the post, it will lose its information.  It will never happen to that specific post after that.

The editing works flawlessly, after that.

Comment: I've re-wrote the actual method I insert information into the database 2 times.

Comment: You have more then 1 error, your whole code is wrong. enable `error_reporting(E_ALL);`

Comment: @LawrenceCherone I'm not getting any errors when I do that.

Comment: what is the name of the page where the form is?

Comment: edit.php is where the form is.   edit-new.php is where it takes you to, to insert information into the database

Comment: could you echo the form content please, just after "edited."?

Comment: Yes, I've done this.  It passes through perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't directly answer your question - it would be useful to know what you're actually getting for `$_GET['id']`, what actual SQL is running on your database and what the generated content of your form looks like.

However:

```
$post = htmlspecialchars($_GET["id"]);
```

Is wrong. `htmlspecialchars` escapes data for *output* to the client. Encoding special characters for SQL is not going to protect you from SQL injection attacks.

Since `$post` is expected to be an integer (presumably), this is sufficient:

```
$post = (int)$_GET['id'];
```

But be sure to check that a valid integer is returned, and throw an appropriate error if not.

Don't forget to do this again in `edit-new.php` - even better, use a parametized value like you have done for `title` and `details`.

Finally, you *should* use `htmlspecialchars` to escape `$details` and `$title` in the form. Otherwise content like `</textarea>` will not be displayed correctly and you are vulnerable to XSS flaws (e.g. followed by `<script>alert("I'm going to do bad things now");</script>`

Comment: $_GET['id'] is getting the post id.  example:  edit.php?id=137